# Neo4j: Duplicated rows when using multiple CALL subqueries

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need some help with building a Cypher query for my problem.

Given the following schema:
[image]

I want to fetch all the children(blue/yellow node), parents(yellow node), and the respective properties(gray node) of their location(green node). Basically, have the following output at the end:

| Parent (yellow node) | Child (yellow/blue) | Parent_property(gray) | Child_property(gray) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

For that, I used UNION to get parent_ids/child_ids from the yellow and blue nodes under same column names, and built 2 separate CALL subqueries (one to fetch id information, and the other for property information). However, I don't know how to proceed next, since I obtained duplicated information after executing the cypher query as it now. I understand that this is due to how CALL subqueries work, however, I don't know how to fix that.

```
//Fetch all parent and children ids
CALL { 
    MATCH (c:subPart)<-[:Has_child]-(p:mainPart{id: "12345"}) RETURN c.id AS child, p.id AS parent
    UNION
    MATCH (m:mainPart)<-[:Has_child]-(p:mainPart {id: "12345"}) RETURN m.id AS child, p.id AS parent
   
} 
//Get property info
MATCH (p)-[]->(r)-[:Has_property]->(property1) 
CALL {
    MATCH (c)-[]->(k)-[:Has_property]->(property2) RETURN property2.name AS child_property
    UNION
    MATCH (m)-[]->(n)-[:Has_property]->(property3) RETURN property3.name AS child_property
}
RETURN child, parent, property1.name AS parent_property, child_property
```

I have also tried to COLLECT parent/ child ids and properties in lists and then UNWIND them, or use the WHERE EXISTS{} clause to filter for the properties, but none of this worked.

I am using Neo4j Desktop 4.3.3 version.

Any help/tips will be very much appreciated! Thank you!

P.S:

Here is a mock dataset that represents the structure of my real data

```
CREATE
 (c: subPart {id: "80"}),
 (p: mainPart {id: "12345"}),
 (m: mainPart {id: "11234"}),
 (k: location {name: "Loc1"}),
 (r: location {name: "Loc2"}),
 (property1: property {name:"X"}),
 (property2: property {name:"Y"}),


 (c)<-[:Has_child]-(p),
 (m)<-[:Has_child]-(p),
 (c)-[:Has_location]->(k),
 (p)-[:Has_location]->(r),
 (m)-[:Has_location]->(r),
 (r)-[:Has_property]->(property1),
 (k)-[:Has_property]->(property2)
```

The code above should output a graph that looks like this:
[image]

And my desired output is:

| Parent | Child | Parent_property | Child_property |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 80 | X | Y |
| 12345 | 11234 | X | X |

I really hope this makes more sense now! Thank you!

Comment: what is the green node?

Comment: Hi @Graphileon! I have updated the post. Hope it's more clear now. Thanks!

Comment: well, to me it's not yet clear. you refer to them as properties (grey) of a location (green), but also as Parent_property and Child_property. Can you add a CREATE statement of a small data set and the expected result, so I can reproduce ?

Comment: Hi @Graphileon, I have added more info! If things don't really add up, let me know! I'm still very new to Neo4j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is as follows:

```
// get the parents and children
MATCH (p)-[:Has_child]->(c)
// for each combination of p and c, use pattern comprehension 
// to get the parent and child properties
WITH p,c,
       [(p)-->(:location)-->(p_prop:property) | p_prop.name][0] as p_prop,
       [(c)-->(:location)-->(c_prop:property) | c_prop.name][0] as c_prop
// return the result
RETURN p.id,c.id,p_prop,c_prop
```

returning this

```
╒═══════╤═══════╤════════╤════════╕
│"p.id" │"c.id" │"p_prop"│"c_prop"│
╞═══════╪═══════╪════════╪════════╡
│"12345"│"80"   │"X"     │"Y"     │
├───────┼───────┼────────┼────────┤
│"12345"│"11234"│"X"     │"X"     │
└───────┴───────┴────────┴────────┘
```

more info on pattern comprehension : https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/lists/#cypher-pattern-comprehension